# Tag for serial (auto increment) primary key

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I want to declare my Go model in an app that uses Postgres.

I am going through [`go-pg`](https://github.com/go-pg/pg). and its related tags.

However in the documentation about the [Model Definition](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/wiki/Model-Definition), there seems to be no tag (?) for a field (pk) to be auto incremented (i.e. the counterpart of `SERIAL` in `postgres` sql definition, e.g. as below

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "day" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
```

How can one declare such an option in the `go` model struct?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `go-pg` but as I understood by walking through the documentation `ID` (or `Id`) field is automatically resolved as a serial and primary key so you don't need to specify that.

From [model definition docs](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/wiki/Model-Definition):

```golang
type Genre struct {
    Id     int // Id is automatically detected as primary key
}
```

```golang
type Author struct {
    ID    int     // both "Id" and "ID" are detected as primary key
}
```